# GeoTools error NumericConverterFactory and GeoServer 2.22.2 with Java 17

Tags: postgis, geoserver, postgresql, java, geotools

We've upgraded to GeoServer 2.22.2 (GeoTools 28.2, Java 17, Postgres 12.7 RDS, PostGIS 3.0.3, Tomcat 9.0.10). Everything runs well except that we get a GeoTools error for a WFS request with a Filter using FID:

[geotools.util] - Error applying the converter class org.geotools.data.util.NumericConverterFactory$NumericConverter on (GISDATA.BARRIERB_POLY.37,class java.lang.Integer) java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "GISDATA.BARRIERB_POLY" Has anyone seen this error?

I'm wondering if this could be an incompatibility with GeoServer 2.22.2 and Java 17 (we skipped from Java 8 to 17). We tried the same WFS query on the same layer with and without the Filter.
Without the Filter the request returns good data instead of the error.

Request:

```
<wfs:GetFeature
      outputFormat="csv"
      xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs"
      service="WFS"
      version="1.1.0"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
      <wfs:Query typeName="massgis:GISDATA.BARRIERB_POLY" srsName="EPSG:26986" xmlns:massgis="http://massgis.state.ma.us/featuretype">    
            <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
                  <ogc:FeatureId fid="GISDATA.BARRIERB_POLY.37"/><ogc:FeatureId fid="GISDATA.BARRIERB_POLY.38"/>
            </ogc:Filter>
      </wfs:Query>
      </wfs:GetFeature>
```

We plan to try to downgrade to Java 11 in NonProd, but wanted to gather some more info first before we spent the effort.

Comment: Try with just 37 in the filter

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it was not a Java version issue but an issue with the "attribute customization" being enabled for a subset of layers. Turning this off fixes our issue for now.